# Is there any way to use lightning:inputField independently?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Based on online documentation and examples available it seems that `lightning:inputField` can only be used inside `lightning:recordEditForm`. But nowhere mentioned that we cannot use it outside of `lightning:recordEditForm`.

Is this possible to use this component independently (e.g. to build a custom form without LDS however taking advantage of standard lookup field)?

Comment: Generally speaking, the documentation does not often specify what you *can't* do. Instead, anything you *can* do is documented. Since there's no documented example of using `lightning:inputField` this way, it really just tells us that you can't do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to use `lightning:inputField` component without wrapping it within `lightning:recordEditForm`.

Refer to the below excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation):

> To create a layout for editing records, use this component with `lightning:recordEditForm` and pass in a *record ID* and *object API name*. To create a layout for creating records, use this component with `lightning:recordEditForm` and pass in the *object API name* of the record you're creating.

The `fieldName` attribute on `lightning:inputField` is the API name and is *wired* to the field name based on the object API name as provided.

If you attempt to use the component without using `lightning:recordEditForm`, the component will not be able to identify with which object the `fieldName` is associated to. Further, it's not really advisable to customize anything around it which potentially may not be supported and you'll end up with more complexities.

Your options are `force:inputField` (will respect the attribute type but doesn't use SLDS styling) or `lightning:input` (uses SLDS styling).

Comment: do you know is there any alternate for lookup field other than using force:inputField and custom component?

Comment: I think that's what you were looking for, right? If you can build a custom component utilizing `force:inputField` (which renders fields based on attribute type) or `lightning:input`, you should be fine.

Comment: How about custom lookup component? like one mentioned here. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005YQsQAM

Comment: Yes Pranay, it was is my last option. Since it has been around 4-5 years lightning rolled out just wanted to check if i am missing something OOTB.